# OpenCV - Save image in DB nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, image, opencv, similarity

I would be so gratefully if someone can help me with this issue:
I'm using opencv with nodejs (https://github.com/TanaseButcaru/node-opencv)

I have an array of photos and I like to read this photos with opencv readImage function and then save this in DB.

```
photos.map(async(photo) => {
    cv.readImage(`${__dirname}/${photo}`, function (error, matrix) { //insert in DB}
```

Do you know how can I save this 'matrix' in DB and then use it to retrieve the image and compare it(ImageSimilarity)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, which of these options are implemented in node-opencv, but:

1. You could either get the uncompressed, raw binary data of the matrix and store it as an array in JSON format (assuming you work with a DB that can store or serialize data in JSON format, like mongodb)
2. Use the imcodec module from OpenCV to encode the image in base64 format, which can basically be stored as a string. However, depending on the codec you may lose image quality, so I would recommend png.

You can also have a look at: https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs, which implements both options. Or atleast the examples of how to serialize a Mat as a JSON array or node buffer may help you, with your problem.

Comment: Hi justadudewhohacks thanks for your comment!
I couldn't use imcodec because is not implemented in node-opencv. I use imageOpenCV.toBuffer function for the image and save it in DB. It was the only way to save in DB.